# Cannot add or update a child row: foreign key with mysql

Tags: mysql

I created two tables students and orders, I tried to add a foreign key to the table "orders" but i have this error :

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

table STUDENTS:

```
 CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (  
 ID varchar(50)  NOT NULL,  
 NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,  
 AGE INT NOT NULL,  
 ADDRESS CHAR (25),  
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
  )
```

Table ORDERS

```
CREATE TABLE Orders  
(O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMAY KEY,  
Order_No int NOT NULL,ID varchar(50))
```

Add foreign key to "orders":

```
ALTER TABLE Orders  
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders  
FOREIGN KEY(ID)  
REFERENCES STUDENTS (ID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if [Orders] table currently has any IDs that are not in [STUDENTS] table.

Comment: +1 This is true, one of tables can contain some records and there is no related record in the second one, so relation cannot be established correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to add foreign key constraint and there is no corresponding primery key in parent table. 
Try to run

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

your ALTER TABLE statement. When you finish run

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```